# Can't connect redux and React to create and delete products

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am learning react and redux and building simple product delete and create. I already define `actions.js`, `Basket.js`, `index.js` and `reducer.js`.  here is the codes

The basket component is already implemented and working as expected. Your task is to connect it with the Redux store and pass three props: `products`, `totalPrice` and an on `onRemove` handler:

`products` should be the list of products taken directly from the store

`totalPrice` should be calculated based on the list of products

`onRemove` is a handler accepting a `productId` parameter, and should dispatch the `removeProductFromBasket` action.

index.js

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";

import basketReducer from "./reducer";
import Basket from "./Basket";
import { addProductToBasket } from "./actions";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  basket: basketReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

function getSampleProduct() {
  return {
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000),
    name: "product 1",
    quantity: 1,
    price: 1.0,
  };
}

function AddProductComponent({ addProduct }) {
  return <button onClick={() => addProduct(getSampleProduct())}>Add product to basket</button>;
}

const AddProduct = connect(null, (dispatch) => ({
  addProduct: (product) => dispatch(addProductToBasket(product)),
}))(AddProductComponent);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Basket />

    <div id="utils">
      <AddProduct />
    </div>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

action.js

```
export function addProductToBasket(product) {
  return {
    payload: product,
    type: "ADD_PRODUCT_TO_BASKET",
  };
}

export function removeProductFromBasket(productId) {
  return {
    payload: { productId },
    type: "REMOVE_PRODUCT_FROM_BASKET",
  };
}
```

Basket.js

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { removeProductFromBasket } from "./actions";

// You can use console.log for debugging purposes.

// This component is already implemented and working as expected.
// `Please focus on Redux related parts.
export function Basket({ products = [], onRemove, totalPrice = 0.0 }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="products">
        {products.map((product) => (
          <li key={product.id} id={product-${product.id}}>
            <span>Name: {product.name}</span>
            <span>Quantity: {product.quantity}</span>
            <button
              id={remove-${product.id}}
              onClick={() => onRemove(product.id)}
            >
              Remove
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div>
        Total price: <span id="total-price">{totalPrice}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Basket);
```

reducer.js

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { removeProductFromBasket } from "./actions";

// You can use console.log for debugging purposes.

// This component is already implemented and working as expected.
// `Please focus on Redux related parts.
export function Basket({ products = [], onRemove, totalPrice = 0.0 }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="products">
        {products.map((product) => (
          <li key={product.id} id={product-${product.id}}>
            <span>Name: {product.name}</span>
            <span>Quantity: {product.quantity}</span>
            <button
              id={remove-${product.id}}
              onClick={() => onRemove(product.id)}
            >
              Remove
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div>
        Total price: <span id="total-price">{totalPrice}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Basket);
```

The basket component is already implemented and working as expected. Your task is to connect it with the Redux store and pass three props: `products`, `totalPrice` and an on `onRemove` handler:

`products` should be the list of products taken directly from the store

`totalPrice` should be calculated based on the list of products

`onRemove` is a handler accepting a `productId` parameter, and should dispatch the `removeProductFromBasket` action.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **functional component**,
then use

- **useSelector** to get store data
- **useDispatch** to dispatch the action

Please, install **react-redux** for the same.
It will be easy to understand!
Still, getting error then we can look into another cause.

*Best of luck! Happy coding...*

Answer (score 0):

Use react hooks in order to make your changes visible by re-rendereing it on the page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).